# Is there inbuilt table or table space available in oracle for temporary basis?

Tags: oracle11g

I need to know if there is any inbuilt table or table space available in oracle to use for temporary basis like dual? In oracle we use temporary table created by our-self for temporary basis but it takes space. So I need to know if instead of creating temp table, if there is any inbuilt tables or table-spaces available in oracle 11g.

This is for oracle 11g

Comment: What do you actually mean by "we use temporary table created by our-self" - actually a [global temporary table](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/tables.htm#ADMIN11633) (which should be created once, not as you need it), or a permanent table you just call 'temp' - which it sounds like you might be creating and dropping repeatedly?

Comment: If we are creating tables for temporary purpose in oracle then it takes memory and might affect i/o if table is heavy. I wanted a temporary table just like you mentioned 'global_temporary_table'. Can you provide me exact syntax for the same(to create the same and use it)?? Also can you tell me if we can use it for bulk data without any effect on database?

Comment: The documentation shows the syntax for a GTT. That does use memory - how much depends on the amount of data inserted by each session - but not disk space, and so no disk I/O. You might also want collections rather than GTTs. Without knowing what you're actually doing it's impossible to say, but those are things to investigate.